# gradle.settings multiline syntax

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have very long `include` in `settings.gradle`:

```
include 'project-subproj1', 'project-subproj2', 'project-subproj3', 'project-subproj4'
```

What proper syntax to split long lines in `settings.gradle`?

I think about:

```
include 'project-subproj1', \
        'project-subproj2', \
        'project-subproj3', \
        'project-subproj4'
```

but seems that

```
include 'project-subproj1',
        'project-subproj2',
        'project-subproj3',
        'project-subproj4'
```

also works.

Is `settings.gradle` a regular Groovy script?

Comment: It's just a regular groovy script like all .gradle files

Comment: @Strelok post that as an answer

Comment: You can prefix everything with include as well, adding each separately which at the end will have the same effect, depends what is cleaner/more readable to you.

Answer (score 7):

**Is settings.gradle a regular Groovy script?**
Yes, it is.

Just to explain a bit, *Gradle* reads the `settings.gradle` file and it actually creates an instance of [Setting](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html#include(java.lang.String[])) class.

If you see the include method spec on the `Setting` class it is like this:

```
void include(java.lang.String[] strings);
```

So the method accepts array of `String` class as argument. In groovy you can call this method in different ways:

```
include "project1", "project2"

include "project1",  
    "project2"

include (['project1',
    'project2'] as String[])

include ('project1',
     'project2')
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in Gradle, each file that ends with `.gradle` is a regular Groovy script. Unscripted files in Gradle are indicated by other file extensions (e.g. `.properties`).

There are several conventions that define special groovy scripts:

- `build.gradle` for the build configuration script
- `settings.gradle` as build setup script
- `init.gradle` in `USER_HOME/.gradle/` for a global initialization script

You can create additional `.gradle` Groovy scripts and use them via `apply from:` or place them at special locations (e.g. `USER_HOME/.gradle/init.d/` to use them as initialization scripts).

The main difference between all these scripts is the context they are applied on. All scripts first implement the [`Script`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.Script.html) interface and a second (role-specific) interface. The Gradle docs call this behaviour "attaching a delegate object".

- `build.gradle` scripts are applied on a [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) object
- `settings.gradle` scripts are applied on a [`Settings`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html) object
- initialization scripts are applied on a [`Gradle`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/invocation/Gradle.html) object

Now, we can even understand the mentioned code example:

```
include 'project-subproj1',
    'project-subproj2',
    'project-subproj3',
    'project-subproj4'
```

The `Settings` interface defines the `include` method, which is called in Groovy style: without brackets and across lines. You could also apply logic in your `settings.gradle` file, e.g. to require a condition before including a specific project.

Comment: nice explanation

Answer (score 2):

Yes, **settings.gradle** is a Groovy script, like other Gradle scripts.
**settings.gradle** is executed in the initialization phase, therefore, it is the multi projects essential file to specify the subprojects, which you can apply in few ways.

You can include each project separately as well, the same effect at the end.

```
include 'project-subproj1'
include 'project-subproj2'
include 'project-subproj3'
include 'project-subproj4'
```

Can iterate through the list.

```
['project-subproj1',
'project-subproj2',
'project-subproj3',
'project-subproj4'].each({include it})
```

Depends on what you feel is more readable/clean for you.